# what am I doing wrong with java.util.Scanner?

Tags: java

This is my Java 1.5 code (complete example):

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class StrangeTest {
  @Test
  public void testRegExp() {
    Pattern re = Pattern.compile("(;|:)[^:;]*");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(":alpha");
    scanner.useDelimiter("");
    assertEquals(":alpha", scanner.next(re)); // failure
  }
}
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically your regular expression matches any string that starts with a `:`, even if it is only one character: `:` matches the expression as well as `:a`, `:al`,... `:alpha`. Even `:alpha;beta` is a match!

With the question mark you appended to your expression you made it *[non-greedy](http://www.itworld.com/nl/perl/01112001)*, i.e. the *shortest* possible string is matched, which is `:`.

Remove the question mark to make it *greedy*:

```
Pattern re = Pattern.compile("(;|:).*");
```

However, then it will match `:alpha;beta`, so you need to indicate that, following the semicolon or colon character, you expect any characters *except* the semicolon or colon:

```
Pattern re = Pattern.compile("(;|:)[^;:]*");
```

Comment: @chiccodoro, the explanation looks correct, but it doesn't change the behavior of the code :( I'm still getting the same result, even with `"(;|:)[^;:]*"`

Comment: @Vincenzo: Might be specific to Java that it does non-greedy by default? Then I suggest to rephrase your question's title to something like "Regex doesn't match as expected". This is catchier, because java.util.Scanner isn't as wellknown as Regex. Further, include these new findings in your question.

Comment: @Vincenzo: What happens if you say `"(;|:)[^;:]+"` (note the plus at the end)?

Comment: @chiccodoro, I just updated the question, with a complete JUnit example. It doesn't work, but it should.. Either `+` or `*` at the end — the same story :(

Comment: @Vincenzo: Why have you accepted my answer? Have you managed to fix it? What did it take to make it work?

Comment: I didn't manage to make it work, instead I'm using `String.split("(?<=;|:)")`. I think that it's a defect in Java. I accepted your answer because it's the most complete among others.

Comment: @Vincenzo: What was the result for `"(;|:)[^;:]+"`? It must be different from `":"` because this isn't even a match.

Comment: @chiccodoro Exactly the same result: `":"`

Comment: @Vincenzo: I'm very surprised, however I don't know how `Scanner` works... How did imerez' proposal?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think the Scanner class works the way your expecting..

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(":alpha;beta");
scanner.useDelimiter("(;|:).*?");
System.out.println(scanner.next()); // gives alpha
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you justify calling `scanner.useDelimiter("");` ? Your matchers work fine if you leave it out..